# Integrating SQLite to Cocos2d-x at Xcode

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, sql

I have downloaded SQLite C/C++ interface to work with Cocos2d-x. Created a database by Firefox SQLite plugin. Then tried the following code

```
    // sqlite implementation
    sqlite3 *db;

    if(sqlite3_open("testdb.sqlite",&db) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Opened db Successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open");
    }
```

Output is # Failed to open

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should start by checking the error code returned by sqlite3_open. Different codes are there for a reason to suggest what the error might be.

I for one guess that the file was not found. Very often the current directory is not what you expect, and is oftent different on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog on how to integrate sqlite in your cocos2d-x game in xcode step by step. You can visit 
http://sqlite-integration-in-cocos2d-x.blogspot.in/

Comment: Welcome! If at all possible, could you try to include the most relevant information from your blog post? It helps ensure you have [the best possible answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) just in case your blog goes offline for any reason.